# OpenGL ES - Drawing one big or multiple small textures. What is better for performance

Tags: performance, opengl-es, gpu

Sometimes ago I have made a following investigation:
Measuring a performance for drawing several textures. I have got the following result:

1. 2 textures 1920x720: ~ 2 mls
2. 1 texture 1920x720 + 2(960x720): ~2 mls
3. 1 texture 1920x720 + 2(960x720): ~2 mls
4. 1 texture 1920x720 + 4(960x360): ~2 mls + 0.09 mls
5. 1 texture 1920x720 + 3(960x720+480x360+480x360): ~2 mls - 0.1 mls

The measurements were made on R-Car H2 SoC, for rendering time measurements was used their software. So I have the following question, what is better to draw:

1. One big or several small images(small images with the same size)
2. One big or several small images(small images with different size)
3. One big mesh or several small meshes(small meshes with the same size)
4. One big mesh or several small meshes(small meshes with different size)

Answer (score 3):

You can pretty much always assume that batching up work is good. If you can do the same thing in fewer draw calls, then do it. If you can make fewer state changes (texture/VBO swaps) then do it.

To answer your questions, render one big texture, render one big mesh.

Comment: In general yes, but as I see from the test in some cases several images could work faster, for me it is also strange. Do you know any description how it must be or it is hardware specific?